# Removing from a MultiSet

Tags: java

So I've been tasked to create a method to remove an element from a MultiSet. I've been trying for a while, but sadly in vain. My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MultiSet<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> {

private HashMap<E, Integer> elements;
private int noOfElems;

public MultiSet() {
    elements = new HashMap<E, Integer>();
    noOfElems= 0;
}

public MultiSet(Collection<E> c) {
    this();
    addAll(c);
}

public int size() {
    return noOfElems;
}

public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<E>() {
        Iterator<E> iterator = elements.keySet().iterator();
        int elemsLeft = 0;
        E thisElem = null;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return iterator.hasNext();
        }

        public E next() {
            if (elemsLeft == 0) {
                thisElem = iterator.next();
                elemsLeft = elements.get(thisElem);
            }

            elemsLeft -= elemsLeft;
            return null;
        }

        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    };
}

public boolean add(E e) {
    Integer i = elements.get(e);
    if(i == null) {
        i = 1;
    } else {
        i += 1;
    } 

    elements.put(e, i);
    noOfElems++;
    return true;
}

public String toString() {
    return elements.toString();
}

public int hashCode() {
    return elements.hashCode();
}

public boolean equals(MultiSet<E> other) {

    if (this == other) {
        return true;
    }

    if (other == null) {
        return false;
    } 

    if (this.getClass() != other.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    MultiSet<?> obj = (MultiSet<?>) other;
    return obj.elements.equals(elements);
    }

    public boolean remove(Object o) {

    }
}
```

And I want to implement the remove method. Anything that will help me, even a few pointers on where to start, will be greatly appreciated. Thanks! (also, comments on the rest of my code will also be appreciated)

Answer (score 0):

This multiset just stores the elements as hash keys mapped to a count of the number of occurrences.  To remove all instances of an element, just delete the key:

```
public void remove_all(E e) {
  elements.remove(e);
}
```

If you need to remove only one instance, then decrement the count unless it's already a 1.  In that case, remove the key.

```
public void remove(E e) {
  Integer i = elements.get(e);
  if (i != null) {
    if (i == 1) {
      elements.remove(e);
    } else {
      elements.put(e,  i - 1);
    }
  }
}
```

BTW it's a bit hard to believe this is your code.  If you understand enough to write the methods you've already written, how could you not know even where to start on `remove`?